# Cannot save to Firestore array of integers and floats

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to save an array of integers and floats.

However, Firestore wont allow me to save that array and does not return an error (in the catch statement for example)

My array is the size of 71201

```
(71201) [84, 96, 96, 96, 91.8, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 96, 95, 93, 91, 89, 88, 87, 87, 87, 88, 89, 91, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 101, 98, 96, 92, 89, 87, 87, 87, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 98, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 121, 122, 122, 122, 123, 124, 124, 125, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, …]
```

Reading the limit [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) the size of an integer is 8 Bytes

So trying to do some math here (and possibly failing)

```
71201*8/1024 = 
556.2578125
```

So that is ~556KB

That as I understand is not a problem with the limit.

Also I can only imagine that this is the problem (not accepting this large array) due to the network tab view:

[image]

Opening one of the requests looks like this on the headers:

[image]

and the response is always empty

[image]

The catch statement of the promise does not get called and I have waited for many minutes (neither the then)

```
this.afs.collection('events').doc(event.getID()).set({values: test}).then((some) => {
      debugger;
    }).catch((e) => {
      debugger;
    });
```

Any ideas what can I be doing wrong?

P.S. It's been now about 20minutes and my network tab keeps growing with those failed requests.

**UPDATE**

If I Make this array a string via eg JSON.stringify then the operation saves within seconds.

Comment: can you share what error you are getting ?

Comment: @rijin I updated the question. Opening the request in the network tab does not show any error, just empty response.

Comment: So what happens if you only send 1/2 the data, or 1/4 of it?

Comment: @charlietfl works on 1/4 for example.

Comment: Its better to go ahead with 1/4 4  times :) ...and wait for someone from firebase team to reply.

Comment: @rijin that array contains heart-rate data (as seen in the example). I need the whole array to plot a chart and I would like to avoid segmentation atm. 
I am just trying to use firestore (perhaps I shouldn't) so here I am testing if my model fits. I mean it's not a production issue.

Comment: which firebase plan are you using? there is write limit https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: @rijin I am on the flexible plan. I checked my quotas and they do look just fine

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the question, but I would recommend using collections instead of arrays to store possibly unbounded time-series data. Firestore arrays need to be updated as whole objects (unless there are some recent advancements that I'm not aware of), which will eventually pose a bandwidth bottleneck.

Comment: As its very nice finding, let me know the total size of records...as it mentioned 1MB for field value... https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: @SamiHult Can you elaborate on this? How would I store this array as a collection?

Comment: @rijin look at my post. The size should of this array is ~550KB

Comment: @JimmyKane Just create a collection (you can create collections under another document) and store the values as individual documents under that. Of course, since you will lose the implicit index, you need to store both the value and index (or any x value, like time): `{ x: time, y: value }`.

Comment: Actually found just out there *have* been some [improvements to the array functionality](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) lately, so the "arrays are evil" may no longer be so true.

Comment: @SamiHult That was the first thing I tried. 
I immediately hit the quota limits. 71201 Heart-rate values .... And that is for one "activity" that the user did. Let aside that I can only batch write 500 values at once.

Comment: How many values do you need to write per second?

Comment: @SamiHult that is a good question. Normally not many, but if you are importing a bike ride then yes many. I could use other mechanisms, but I am trying to "fit" this to the firestore, but it seems not to be fitiing atm. 

If you are familiar with .fit files and the domain of activity tracking here is the project to take a look https://quantified-self.io

Comment: I'm afraid that currently your most feasible options are: 1) store the data as a blob, losing ability to query it, 2) change database to Cloud SQL, Cloud Bigtable, Cloud Datastore or similar. Firestore is, after all, still beta.

Comment: @SamiHult thanks for the chat time and suggestions. I might end up storing those as blobs in the end and I think its fine not to be able to be queried.

Comment: "I need the whole array to plot a chart and I would like to avoid segmentation atm" In cases where I don't need to query inside a JSON structure, I often store the data as a string. This performs much better, since the database doesn't have to index the individual array elements.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think I have found my way :-) Blob of array. Will check comparison vs string vs LZ string